# Pine script related

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

The following Pine script code is giving error while compiling:

```
plot(ema(close,9), color=red, linewidth=1) 
plot(ema(close,21), color=#5878DA, linewidth=1) 
plot(ema(close,50), color=#297F87, linewidth=1) 
plot(ema(close,200), color=#83d13a, linewidth=1, style = plot.style_circles) 
plot(vwap, color=#FFB830, linewidth=2, style = plot.style_cross)
```

Can anyone pl point out the mistake?

Trying to plot ema's - 9,21,50, 200 and vwap in tradingview using the above pinescript.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mixture of different pinescript versions. Based on the code you shared, it looks like you are using `v4`. Change `red` to `color.red` and it should compile.

Answer (score 0):

following code will work correctly

```
//@version=5
indicator("my script", overlay = true)

plot(ta.ema(close,9), color=color.red, linewidth=1) 
plot(ta.ema(close,21), color=#5878DA, linewidth=1) 
plot(ta.ema(close,50), color=#297F87, linewidth=1) 
plot(ta.ema(close,200), color=#83d13a, linewidth=1, style = plot.style_circles) 
plot(ta.vwap, color = #FFB830, linewidth = 2, style = plot.style_cross)
```